# Another Binomial Coefficient Congruence Modulo Prime Powers

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I have the following conjecture on binomials modulo prime powers:

Let $s, b, n \ge 0$ be integers, let $p$ be a prime and let $0\le k_0 < p^{b+1}$ and $0\le n_0 < p^{b+s}$, then we have the following congruence:
$$
\binom{n p^{s+b} + n_0}{ k_0} \equiv \binom{n_0}{k_0} \pmod{p^s} .
$$

The case $s=1$ follows directly from Lucas' theorem, since:
$$
\binom{n p^{1+b} + n_0}{ k_0}
\equiv
\binom{n}{ 0}
\binom{n_0}{k_0} \pmod{p} .
$$

The generalization to powers is quite similar to [Davis and Webb's Theorem 3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X83710024) which is a generalization of Lucas' theorem, and says that if $n, k, r, s$ are positive integers then

$$
\binom{n p^{s+b} + n_0}{k p^{s+b} + k_0} \equiv \binom{np^{s-1}}{kp^{s-1}}\binom{n_0}{k_0} \pmod{p^s} .
$$

Under the condition that $0\le k_0,n_0 < p^{b+1}$.

The difference is that Davis and Webb have a stronger restriction on $n_0$, while I have a stronger restriction on $k$. (I require $k=0$.)

As far as I can tell there is no way to prove on of the statements from the other. But both numerically appear to be true. (Well, the second one is a theorem, so that's not surprising.)

Can anyone help help me determine if my conjecture is true?

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem 1:**
Let $ p $ be a prime and let $ s $ and $\ell$ be positive integers.
For any integers $n$, and $k$, such that $k < p^{\ell}$,
write $n=n_1 p^{\ell+s-1} + n_0$ where $ 0 \leq n_0 < p^{\ell+s-1}$.
The following congruence holds:
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k} \equiv \binom{n_0}{k} \pmod {p^s}.&& (1)
\end{align}

The case $s=1$ is easy to prove using the classic result known as Lucas' Theorem: $\binom{n}{k}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^m \binom{n_i}{k_i} \pmod{p}$, where $n=\sum_{i=0}^m n_i p^i$ is the base $p$ expansion of $n$, and $k$ is similarly represented.
Since $\binom{n}{0}=1$, and $k_i=0$ for $i \ge \ell$, we can similarly limit $n$ to the first $\ell$ digits, which is exactly $n_0$, as $\ell+s-1=l$ in this case.
Lucas Theorem thus gives us directly:
$$
\binom{n}{k}
\equiv\prod_{i=0}^m \binom{n_i}{k_i}
\equiv\prod_{i=0}^\ell \binom{n_i}{k_i}
\equiv\binom{n_0}{k}
\pmod{p}.
$$

The case $s>1$ is more tricky, and we will need some more powerful tools.

**Proof:**
We consider two cases: one, if $p^s$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$;
and two, if it doesn't.

**Case: $p^s$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$:**
In the first case, the lhs. of eq. (1) is 0, so we need to show the rhs. is zero too, that is $p^s$ divides $\binom{n_0}{k}$.
We'll use Kummer's Theorem, which says:
"If $n$ and $k$ are integers and $p$ is a prime, then the largest power of $p$ dividing $\binom n k$ is given by the number of borrows required when subtracting the base $p$ representations of $k$ from $n$."
So we need to show that $n_0 - k$ has as many borrows as $n-k$.
However, this is clearly the case when $n_0 \ge k$.
And when $n_0 < k$ the rhs. of eq. (1) is 0 by the definition of binomial coefficients.

**Case: $p^s$ does not divide $\binom{n}{k}$:**
For the second case, where $p^s$ doesn't divide $\binom{n}{k}$
we will use the following result of Davis and Webb:

**Theorem:**
Let $p$ be any prime, and $s$ be a non-negative integer.
Define $n$ and $m$
\begin{align*}
n &= n_0 + n_1 p + \ldots + n_{\ell-1} p^{\ell-1},
\\
m &= m_0 + m_1 p + \ldots + m_{\ell-1} p^{\ell-1}.
\end{align*}
for some $\ell$ large enough,
such that $0\le n_i, m_i < p$ for each $i$.
Further define the "length $s$ blocks" of $n$ as
$$
n[i:i+s] = n_i + n_{i+1} p + \dots + n_{i+s-1} p^{s-1},
$$
and equivalently for $m$.

Then
\begin{align*}
\\
\text{where}
\quad
P = \prod_{i=0}^{\ell-s} \binom{n[i:i+s]}{m[i:i+s]}
\quad\text{and}\quad
Q = \prod_{j=1}^{\ell-s} \binom{n[i:i+s-1]}{m[i:i+s-1]},
\end{align*}
and $ Q^{-1} $ denotes the modular multiplicative inverse of $ Q $ modulo $ p^s $.

**Note:**
As a technical detail Davis and Webb redefine the value of the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{m}$ when $n < m$.
Instead of being 0, we define in this case
\begin{align*}
    \binom{n[i:j+1]}{m[i:j+1]}
    =
    \begin{cases}
        \phantom{p} \binom{n[i:j]}{m[i:j]}
        &\text{if}\quad n_{j} = m_{j}
        \\
        p \binom{n[i:j]}{m[i:j]}
        & \text{if}\quad n_{j} < m_{j}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

**Note:**
The requirement that $p^s$ does not divide $\binom{n}{k}$ is important.
Consider for example $p=2$, $s=2$ and $\ell=3$.
Take
\begin{align*}
n &= 0 + 0\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 2^2 = 4,
\\
m &= 1 + 0\cdot 2 + 0\cdot 2^2 = 1.
\end{align*}
In this case $\binom{4}{1} = 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^2}$.
But
$
P =
\binom{0 + 0\cdot 2}{1 + 0\cdot 2}
\binom{0 + 1\cdot 2}{0 + 0\cdot 2}
=
\binom{0}{1}
\binom{2}{0}
= 2\cdot1
= 2
$
and
$
Q=\binom{0}{0}=1.
$
So $PQ^{-1}=2 \not\equiv 0 \pmod {2^2}$.
Hence special casing $p^s$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$, like we did earlier, is necessary.

We continue to prove the main Theorem in the case $p^s$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$.
To avoid issues with notation, let's write it as
$\binom{n}{k} \equiv \binom{n'}{k} \pmod {p^s}.$
where $n \equiv n' \pmod{p^{\ell+s-1}}$.
Pick $L$ large enough that $n<p^L$.
Then applying Davis and Webb's Theorem to the left hand side we get:
\begin{align*}
P
&= \prod_{i=0}^{L-s} \binom{n[i:i+s]}{k[i:i+s]}
= \prod_{i=0}^{\ell-1} \binom{n[i:i+s]}{k[i:i+s]}
\prod_{i=\ell}^{L-s}\binom{n[i:i+s]}{0}
,
\\
Q &= \prod_{j=1}^{L-s} \binom{n[i:i+s-1]}{k[i:i+s-1]}
= \prod_{j=1}^{\ell-1} \binom{n[i:i+s-1]}{k[i:i+s-1]}
\prod_{j=\ell}^{L-s} \binom{n[i:i+s-1]}{0},
\end{align*}
Since $k < p^\ell$.
Now, as $\binom{n}{0}=1$ for all $n$,
we see that the highest $i$ such that the value of $n_i$ matters is $n_{\ell+s-2}$.
By definition $n'_i = n_i$ for all $i \le \ell+s-2$,
so applying Davis and Webb to the right hand side of eq. (1) we get the same value, proving the original congruence.
$\square$